# Transact-Sql INTO Clause Syntax

Tags: t-sql

What am I doing wrong here? My use of the INTO clause seems to match the example I found in Microsoft's Transact-SQL reference pages, but I must be missing something.

```
DECLARE @rowtemp table(TestRunID int, RunOrder int)

SELECT TestRunID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TestRuns.TestTime ASC) 
AS 'RunOrder' INTO @rowtemp FROM TestRuns WHERE RunID = @runID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use SELECT INTO with a table variable and also SELECT INTO would create a table so you would not create the table first

try this

```
DECLARE @rowtemp table(TestRunID int, RunOrder int)

INSERT INTO  @rowtemp
SELECT TestRunID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TestRuns.TestTime ASC) 
AS 'RunOrder'  FROM TestRuns WHERE  RunID = @runID
```

Comment: This is one of a number of key differences between temporary tables and table variables

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a table variable with a SELECT INTO.  Use a # temp table instead.

Answer (score 1):

Table variables cannot be used with SELECT INTO, you can use a #temp table or rearrange your statement slightly to read.

```
DECLARE @rowtemp table(TestRunID int, RunOrder int)

INSERT INTO @rowtemp 
 SELECT 
  TestRunID, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TestRuns.TestTime ASC) AS 'RunOrder' 
FROM 
 TestRuns 
WHERE 
 RunID = @runID
```

Answer (score 0):

What Joe said.  Plus, INTO creates a new table.  Since this table already exists (you just created it) the statement fails.